# dbExpress error in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress

The below code works in Delphi 2007, but it gives me this error in Delphi 2010:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Cannot load oci.dll library (error code 127).
The oci.dll library may be missing from the system path
or you may have an incompatible version of the
library installed.
---------------------------
OK   Details >>   
---------------------------
```

The exception is raised when I set "connected" to "true".

I have tried placing a copy of "oci.dll" in the same folder as the .exe file, but I get the same message.

I also get this message when using the form designer and a visible TSQLConnection component.

Any thoughts?

```
function TDBExpressConnector.GetConnection(username, password, servername: string) : TSQLConnection;
begin
  //take a username, password, and server
  //return a connected TSQLConnection
  try
    FSqlDB := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
    with FSqlDB do begin
      Connected := False;
      DriverName := 'Oracle';
      GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverORACLE';
      KeepConnection := True;
      LibraryName := 'dbxora30.dll';
      ConnectionName := 'OracleConnection';;

      Params.Clear;
      Params.Add('DriverName=Oracle');
      Params.Add('DataBase=' + servername);
      Params.Add('User_Name=' + username);
      Params.Add('Password=' + password);
      Params.Add('RowsetSize=20');
      Params.Add('BlobSize=-1');
      Params.Add('ErrorResourceFile=');
      Params.Add('LocaleCode=0000');
      Params.Add('Oracle TransIsolation=ReadCommited');
      Params.Add('OS Authentication=False');
      Params.Add('Multiple Transaction=False');
      Params.Add('Trim Char=False');
      Params.Add('Decimal Separator=.');

      LoginPrompt := False;
      Connected := True;
    end;

    Result := FSqlDB;
  except on e:Exception do
    raise;
  end;  //try-except
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 2010 the dbExpress driver for Oracle is dbxora.dll. The libraryname in your named connection says dbxora30.dll. Good chance it will work with the correct name!

Comment: Sadly, it does not make any difference.  Thanks though

Answer (score -2):

See the problem and the fix here: [My Blog](http://gfaggiano.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/fixing-dbexpress-libmysql-dll-error-in-radstudio-2009-2010/)

Just substitute your dll for the one I mention in my post.  You should find it in the same directory.